# GCC pointer cast warning

Tags: pointers, gcc, casting, warnings

I am wondering why GCC is giving me this warning:

```
test.h: In function TestRegister:
test.h:12577: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

Code:

```
#define Address   0x1234
int TestRegister(unsigned int BaseAddress)
{
    unsigned int RegisterValue = 0;
    RegisterValue              = *((unsigned int *)(BaseAddress + Address)) ;
    if((RegisterValue & 0xffffffff) != (0x0 << 0))
    {
            return(0);
    }
    else
    {
            return(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 12577?  You should think about refactoring your code...

Comment: Is your platform 64-bit?

Comment: I'm curious to the purpose of `(0x0 << 0)`, and of the whole line containing it, as it seems `(RegisterValue != 0)` represents the same condition.

Comment: I presume that depends on the size of the `int` … the `0xffffffff` could potentially be masking off upper words on some esoteric system where an `int` is larger than 32 bits :-/

Comment: Its autogenerated code..Hence 0x0 << 0  and line 12577.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you're on a 64-bit platform, where pointers are 64-bit but `int`s are 32-bit.

Rule-of-thumb: Don't try to use integers to store addresses.

Comment: What data type should I use to store addresses ?

Comment: @alertjean: A pointer.  Ideally a pointer to the data-type you want to use.  Failing that, a `void *`, but note that you cannot do pointer arithmetic on a `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

If you include `<stdint.h>` and if you compile [for the C99 standard](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) using `gcc -Wall -std=c99` you could cast to and from `intptr_t` which is an integer type of the same size as pointers.

```
RegisterValue = *((unsigned int *)((intptr_t)(BaseAddress + Address))) ;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I could not recall what this type was named. This is useful, for example, when you have a 32 bit process that needs to work with the address space of a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you're assuming that a pointer will *fit* into an `unsigned int`, where C gives *no such guarantee*… there are a number of platforms in use today where this is untrue, apparently including yours.

A pointer to data can be stored in a `(void*)` or (type`*`) safely. Pointers can be added to (or subtracted to yield) a `size_t` or `ssize_t`. There's no guaranteed relationship between `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(size_t)`, `sizeof(ssize_t)`, and `(void*)` or (type`*`)…

(Also, in this case, there's no real point in initializing the var and overwriting it on the next line…)

Also unrelated, but you realise that `!= (0x0 << 0)` → `!= 0` and can be omitted, since `if (x)` = `if (x != 0)` … ? Perhaps that's because this is cut down from a larger sample, but that entire routine could be presented as

```
   int TestRegister (unsigned int* BaseAddress)
     { return ( (0xffffffff & *(BaseAddress + Address)) ? 0 : 1 ); }
```

(Edited: changed to `unsigned int*` as it seems far more likely he wants to skip through at `int`-sized offsets?)

Comment: Good point, d'oh. The "Cheat" here is to use an `unsigned char*` and hope that `char` is a byte :-)

Comment: Also, as @jv42 pointed out, the `0xffffffff &` is probably pointless, if the size of an `int` is 32 bits or less, and could be omitted, as well. … Not sure about the logic there, in point of fact, the parameter might have been meant to be an `int*` to skip through the address space at `int`-sized offsets? …

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Note that gcc permits arithmetic on `void*` as an extension.  To put it another way, by default it fails to diagnose the error of attempting to do arithmetic on `void*`.